# How to upscale image to cover div but not over image original size?

Tags: image, css

Is there any way (with CSS) to make the image to cover a div element, but only if it can be done without overriding the original dimensions on upscaling?

That to prevent pixelated image. Object-fit `'cover'` upscales even too small images. And `'contain'` don't push the image to cover the div.

So, is there a way to accomplish what I want?

**Edit:**

Seems that even `'contain'` works that bad way. It upscaling the image to the parent element's edges even if that makes the image bigger than the original. That's crazy...Isn't it?

And I'm trying to see if it's possible to at least add image sizes in Wordpress by just the aspect ratio, not an exact size. I just want to change, crop to a given ratio for the image. That could at least help a bit. But no, there's no function for that. Just the image editor you can use after the upload...

**Where is the responsive thinking?** Isn't aspect ratio the future, not pixels?

Comment: No, there's no way for CSS to know when an image is "too pixelated" according to a random person in real life.

Comment: Do you want to have a image behave like `cover` but without getting cropped?

Comment: @TylerH That's not what I meant. As I said I don't want it to be upscaled if that will override the original image size.

Comment: @Gerrit Halfmann No, I want it to be cropped. But I don't want the image to be upscaled at all if the image is too small and will override it's original dimensions.

Comment: It seems to be a job for **[`<picture>`](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/)** (and its polyfill for IE11)

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research and can offer you this solution:

- Image needs to be a background-image
- Set a fixed width for the `background-size` + auto
- (optional) you can center the image for aesthetics

In this example the `.img-container` is also flexible (`20vh`) and crops the image if it gets smaller then 100px. The fixed `background-size` value prevents the image from scaling up aswell.

> created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qtqcuoq/1/) to check the flexible container

```css
.img-container {
  width: 60vh;
  height: 60vh;
  border: 2px solid #111;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100px auto;

  background-image: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, but I guess it doesn't work for images below 100px width? And that wide images won't be cropped. They will act as 'contain' instead? If I don't change it to `background-size: auto 100px;`?

Comment: You can do it only with fixed img-widths and fixed css values. Like @TylerH said, CSS cannot know if a image gets pixelated. We can only define that e.g. 48x48 `background-images` do not get bigger then 48x48 pixel.

Comment: Forget about pixelated. I just don't want the image to upscale over it's original size. CSS seems to at least know the image's dimensions, width and height.